# How to split lines in one part of a text file differently from another? - Perl

Tags: perl

I’m very new to coding.

I have data in a text file formatted as follows:

```
#
PROPERTY_A: TEXT1
PROPERTY_B: UNIT1
#
PROPERTY_A: TEXT2
PROPERTY_B: UNIT2
#
#
1 2
3 4
```

I want to output it as a table like so:

```
TEXT1 TEXT2
UNIT1 UNIT2
1     2
3     4
```

I understand how to read the text file into an array of lines and then how to use split() to parse each line into and array of strings. I want to write the data into a table with the properties as the headers of each column so I will need to split using “: “ until I read 2 consecutive lines with a hash on then change to using “ “ to split.

Using this code gives me an infinite loop that doesn’t return any value even through both individual splits work fine.

```
my $dataAsText = SomeFunction->Run($imputDocument);
for (my $ln = 0; < $dataAsText->Lines->Count; ++$ln;)
my $line = $dataAsText->Lines($ln)
do {
   my @words = split ($line, ‘: ‘, 2);
   # then pass @words[1] to the first or second row of each column
} until ($line eq ‘#’ && $line + 1 eq ‘#’);
   my @words = split ($line, ‘ ‘);
   # then pass each @words values to its corresponding column
}
```

How would I write a piece of code to check for 2 consecutive lines with hash symbols then change how the lines are split before they’re sent to the arrays?

Just to clarify the final data document may have hundreds of thousands of lines to read, this is an example structure.

Comment: I don't understand what output you want -- can you show that, using data from the file you show?  Also, the shown code doesn't make much sense as it stands -- can you show more, in particular how you read and iterate over lines?

Comment: Thank you for clarifying things.  But: when you say "_Using this code gives me_" it seems to refer to the code you show, what is not possible since that is very far from correect Perl and won't compile (on many accounts).

Answer (score 1):

You can try command line Perl

```
perl -F: -ane ' if(not /^\d+/) { $x.=$F[1] if not /^#/ } else { $y.=$_ } 
    END { $x=~s/\s*(\S+)\s*(\S+)\s*(\S+)\s*(\S+)/$1 $3\n$2 $4/gs; print $x,$y }' file
```

with your given inputs:

```
$ cat marPar.txt
#
PROPERTY_A: TEXT1
PROPERTY_B: UNIT1
#
PROPERTY_A: TEXT2
PROPERTY_B: UNIT2
#
#
1 2
3 4

$ perl -F: -ane ' if(not /^\d+/) { $x.=$F[1] if not /^#/ } else { $y.=$_ } 
      END { $x=~s/\s*(\S+)\s*(\S+)\s*(\S+)\s*(\S+)/$1 $3\n$2 $4/gs; print $x,$y }' marPar.txt
TEXT1 TEXT2
UNIT1 UNIT2
1 2
3 4

$
```

Comment: @zdim.. thanks.. just updated.. I have one more question.. how to print the ````$'```` , the right section after a regex match in one-liner solutions..

Comment: Wow, a good one ... dunno.  Except for using its ["english" name](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#$')  `perl -MEnglish -wE'$_=q(abc); /./; say $POSTMATCH'`.  In Perls earlier than (..X?) this incurred performance penalty while `${^POSTMATCH}` does the same with no penalty.  But I think that there is no penalty in any case anymore. (Using `"` as script delimiter was either way too messy or didn't work)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do. What you want to do is detect lines starting with a hash and count them; when you see two in a row, swap the pattern you're using to do the split.

```
{
  # Inside a block so only the sub here can see them.
  my $double_hash_seen;
  my $splitter = qr/:/;   # First split pattern
  my $last_was_hash;

  sub split_appropriately {
    my($line) = @_;
    if (/^#/) {
      if ($last_was_hash) {
        # Double hash, switch modes.
        $splitter = qr/ /;  # Second split pattern
        return;             # We don't split hash lines
      }
      # Last was not a hash, but this was.
      $last_was_hash = 1;  # One hash seen.
      return;              # Don't split the hash line
    }
    # This isn't a hash. Turn off "hash seen" and split
    # with appropriate current pattern.
    $last_was_hash = 0;
    split $splitter, $line;  # Will stay switched once it changes
  }
}

while(<DATA>) {
  my($first, $second) = split_appropriately($_);
  next unless defined $first;
  print "Part 1: $first\n";
  print "Part 2: $second\n";
}
__DATA__
#
PROPERTY_A: TEXT1
PROPERTY_B: UNIT1
#
PROPERTY_A: TEXT2
PROPERTY_B: UNIT2
#
#
1 2
3 4
```